# Cannot find `/etc/letsencrypt/live/` in a container

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt

I have a server working well with the following `docker-compose.yml`. I can find in container `/etc/letsencrypt/live/v2.10studio.tech/fullchain.pem` and `/etc/letsencrypt/live/v2.10studio.tech/privkey.pem`.

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: staticfloat/nginx-certbot
    ports:
      - 80:8080/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
    environment:
      CERTBOT_EMAIL: owner@company.com
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/user.conf.d:ro
      - letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
  10studio:
    image: bitnami/nginx:1.16
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./build:/app
      - ./default.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/default.conf:ro
      - ./configs/config.prod.js:/app/lib/config.js
    depends_on: 
    - frontend

volumes:
  letsencrypt:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: 10studio
```

I tried to create another server with the same setting, but I could not find `live` under `/etc/letsencrypt` of the container.

Does anyone know what's wrong? where do files under `/etc/letsencrypt/live` come from?

**Edit 1:**

I have one file `conf.d/.conf`, I tried to rebuild and got the following message:

```
root@iZj6cikgrkjzogdi7x6rdoZ:~/10Studio/pfw# docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --no-deps
Creating pfw_pfw_1 ... done
Creating pfw_10studio_1 ... done
Attaching to pfw_pfw_1, pfw_10studio_1
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.60 
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.60 Welcome to the Bitnami nginx container
pfw_1       | templating scripts from /etc/nginx/user.conf.d to /etc/nginx/conf.d
pfw_1       | Substituting variables 
pfw_1       |  -> /etc/nginx/user.conf.d/*.conf
pfw_1       | /scripts/util.sh: line 116: /etc/nginx/user.conf.d/*.conf: No such file or directory
pfw_1       | Done with startup
pfw_1       | Run certbot
pfw_1       | ++ parse_domains
pfw_1       | ++ for conf_file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf*
pfw_1       | ++ xargs echo
pfw_1       | ++ sed -n -r -e 's&^\s*ssl_certificate_key\s*\/etc/letsencrypt/live/(.*)/privkey.pem;\s*(#.*)?$&\1&p' /etc/nginx/conf.d/certbot.conf
pfw_1       | + auto_enable_configs
pfw_1       | + for conf_file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf*
pfw_1       | + keyfiles_exist /etc/nginx/conf.d/certbot.conf
pfw_1       | ++ parse_keyfiles /etc/nginx/conf.d/certbot.conf
pfw_1       | ++ sed -n -e 's&^\s*ssl_certificate_key\s*\(.*\);&\1&p' /etc/nginx/conf.d/certbot.conf
pfw_1       | + return 0
pfw_1       | + '[' conf = nokey ']'
pfw_1       | + set +x
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.60 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-nginx
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.61 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-nginx/issues
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.61 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.61 
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.62 INFO  ==> ** Starting NGINX setup **
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.64 INFO  ==> Validating settings in NGINX_* env vars...
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.64 INFO  ==> Initializing NGINX...
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.65 INFO  ==> ** NGINX setup finished! **
10studio_1  | 
10studio_1  |  11:25:33.66 INFO  ==> ** Starting NGINX **
```

If I do `docker-compose up -d --build`, I still cannot find `/etc/letsencrypt/live` in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after changing `ports: - 80:8080/tcp` to `ports: - 80:80/tcp`.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the [original site of this image `staticfloat/nginx-certbot`](https://hub.docker.com/r/staticfloat/nginx-certbot), it will create and automatically renew website SSL certificates.

With the configuraiton file under `./conf.d`

Create a config directory for your custom configs:

```
$ mkdir conf.d
And a .conf in that directory:

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         server.company.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.company.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.company.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

because `/etc/letsencrypt` is mounted from a persistent volume `letsencrypt`

```
services:
  frontend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: staticfloat/nginx-certbot
    ...
    volumes:
      ...
      - letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

volumes:
  letsencrypt:
```

If you need reference `/etc/letsencrypt/live`, you need mount the same volume `letsencrypt` into your new application as well

Comment: I do have `conf.d/pf.conf` and I can see `/etc/nginx/user.conf.d/pf.conf` in the container. But I cannot see `/etc/letsencrypt/live` in the container.

Comment: Please see my `Edit 1`.

Answer (score -1):

As `/etc/letsencrypt` is a mounted volume that is persisted over restarts of your container, I would assume that any process added these files to the volume. According to a quick search using my favorite search engine, `/etc/letsencrypt/live` is filled with files after creating certificates